# foo&& r = foo(); rはlvalue reference?

Tags: c++, c++11

以下のコード

```
#include <iostream>
class foo
{

};

void f(foo&& r)
{
    std::cout << "rvalue ref" << std::endl;
}
void f(foo& r)
{
    std::cout << "lvalue ref" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo&& r = foo();

    std::cout << "foo() is ";
    f(foo());
    std::cout << "r is ";
    f(r);

    return 0;
}
```

において出力結果は

```
foo() is rvalue ref
r is lvalue ref
```

となりました。

```
foo() is rvalue ref
```

は理解できますが

```
r is lvalue ref
```

となるのは驚きでした。
r は foo&& すなわちfooへのrvalue referenceのはずですから
f(r)はf(foo&& r)にオーバーロード解決されるであろうと予測していたからです。

しかし、f(foo& r)にオーバーロード解決されているということは
r は lvalue referenceということでしょうか？

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> r は lvalue referenceということでしょうか？

少し違います。**式`r`** のvalue categoryは **左辺値(lvalue)** であるため、左辺値参照(lvalue referenece)をとるオーバーロード`f(foo& r)`が選択されたという解釈になります。

紛らわしいのですが、変数の型(type) と 式のvalue categoryは異なる概念です。

- 変数`r` の型は「右辺値参照(rvalue reference)」(`foo&&`)です。
- 式`r` のvalue categoryは「左辺値(lvalue)」です。

Comment: 混乱していた思考がスッキリしました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

名前を付けた変数は、その名前やメンバーはlvalueです。(もし`class foo`が`int x`というメンバーが含んでいたら、`foo().x`はrvalueが、`r.x`はlvalueです)

[Value categories - cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)

> lvalue
>
> The following expressions are lvalue expressions:
>
> the name of a variable or a function in scope, regardless of type, such as `std::cin` or `std::endl`. Even if the variable's type is rvalue reference, the expression consisting of its name is an lvalue expression

スタック変数の他には、パラメータのrvalueも実際にlvalueに取り扱われます。

その掟は、以下の誤用を防止します

```
void g(std::unique_ptr<int> q) { /* .. */ }

void f(std::unique_ptr<int>&& p) {
    g(p); // たとえpはrvalue、ここでgのパラメータにmoveされて
    // ...
    g(p); // もう一度pでgを呼び出してしまったら、gのパラメータはnullptrです
}
```

ですから、なるべくrvalue reference型のスタック変数を宣言しないようにします。パラメータのrvalueそのまま転送したいなら、`std::move`や`std::forward`を使用します。